# Pandas : Python how to do index Groupby with replicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame similar to this:

```
list1 = [4656, 5455, 4545, 6992, 4233, 4596, 4699, 4899, 7896, 4526, 4872, 6952]
list2 = [4466, 4899, 4554, 4771, 1477, 1445, 4523, 1456, 3695, 6258, 1452, 4878]
index1= ['A50_C1','A50_C2','A50_I1','A50_I2','A50_N1','A50_N2','A60_C1','A60_C2','A60_I1','A60_I2','A60_N1','A60_N2']
s1 = pd.Series(list1, index=index1, name='list1')
s2 = pd.Series(list2, index=index1, name='list2')
pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
```

Here is what it looks like:

```
         list1    list2
test
A50_C1    4656    4466
A50_C2    5455    4899
A50_I1    4545    4554   
A50_I2    6992    4771
A50_N1    4233    1477
A50_N2    4596    1445
A60_C1    4699    4523
A60_C2    4899    1456
A60_I1    7896    3695
A60_I2    4526    6258
A60_N1    4872    1452
A60_N2    6952    4878
```

I would like to make a groupby with the Index (test column)
for that i'm using :
df2 = df1.groupby(df1.index)
It seems to work but it is grouping several time the same row (probably to create the different combination possibles).

So i can't figured out how to groupby replicates in the Index ie: C1-C2 ; I1-I2 ; N1-N2

The result should look like this:

```
          list1    list2
test
A50_C1    4656    4466
A50_C2    5455    4899

          list1    list2
test
A50_I1    4545    4554   
A50_I2    6992    4771

          list1    list2
test
A50_N1    4233    1477
A50_N2    4596    1445
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to add a column to your DataFrame containing the information you want to group on.  Each value in your index is just a single string; pandas can't guess which parts of it you want to group on, so you need to explicitly extract just the parts that are relevant for your grouping.

Based on your example, it looks like what you actually want to group on is the contents of the index not including the last character.  So make that a column:

```
df['label'] = df.index.to_series().str[:-1]
```

Now you can just do `df.groupby('label')` to group on your desired feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your method seems to work well ;) However by curiosity i was wondering if there is a way to specify the groupby to groupby every 2 rows or 3 rows etc if the values are sorted it may work also?

Comment: @Jérémz: Again, the way to do that is to make a column (or even just a separate list) containing the values you want to group by.  If you want to group by consecutive rows, make a list or column like `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ...]` and group by that.